# Prove that {F,→} is functionally complete

Tags: boolean-logic

> How can I prove that {F,→} is functionally complete?

I am trying to write p∧q using only those symbols but I really have no idea how to solve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has more to do with formal math and logic than programming. Perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com would be better? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [truth table of implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication):

[image]

If you fix input `Q` to `F` (false), the output is the inverse of input `P`.
Therefore, implication and `F` can be combined to an inverter.

`P implies Q` can be written as `Q or not P`. Both have the same truth tables.
This demonstrates, that implication is equivalent to a disjunction with one inverted input. Using the inverter shown above, we get a disjunction (inclusive or).

Apply [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to see that `P implies Q` is also equivalent to `not (P and not Q)`. This shows that we can turn an implication into a conjunction.

Disjunction plus negation as well as conjunction combined with negation are functionally complete. Hence, implication combined with a `false` constant is also functionally complete. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicational_propositional_calculus#Completeness) for a formal proof.